# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while adapter of recycle view is trying to get the size

Tags: android

I have a recycle view with pagination. When the user scrolls to bottom I am getting more items and put them into adapter like so:

```
public void addMoreItem(List<Item> newItems) {

        if (items != null) {

            items.addAll(newItems);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

but I receve the exception java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when the adapter is trying to get the size:

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return items.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to be more precise without seeing your code and your stacktrace, but you should not add elements when the user is scrolling, because the adapter is trying to read the elements in the meanwhile.

List adapter are made to take care of what elements should be displayed, so if you can, just add all elements at the beginning.

If you can't, you should add your elements at another time, for instance after the scroll